# Какой эквивалент у char** из C++ в Delphi?

Tags: c++, строки, delphi, указатели

Написана DLL на С++ в которой есть метод с возвращаемым двумерным массивом `char**`. Как тип (`char**`) привести в соответствие типу в Delphi?

Answer (score 7):

Для использования в DLL в Delphi есть тип `PPChar` - указатель на указатель на `Char`.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.PPChar

```
Type
  PChar  = ^Char;
  PPChar = ^PChar;
```

**Дополнение**

В современных версиях Delphi по умолчанию String и Char стали юникодными в формате, совместимом с WinAPI, то есть UTF-16LE.

Если нужно использовать именно однобайтный Char, то он теперь называется AnsiChar, соответственно указатель PAnsiChar, а указатель на указатель — PPAnsiChar

Comment: Ещё следует учитывать  - строки ансишные или юникодные.

Comment: Вот только не юникодные, а utf16.

Comment: @KoVadim, а utf16 - не юникод?

Comment: не совсем. utf16, utf8, ucs2 и ещё ряд названий - это способ кодировать юникод в реальные байтики.  Поэтому, говоря, что строка юникодная, мы ничего не говорим. Вот вообще ничего. А вот говорить "широкие строки" (Wide) - более практично, так как тут уже явно обычно говорим о 2 байтовой кодировке (и обычно это utf16+суррогатные пары). А ещё есть порядок байт... ух...   Возвращаясь к вопросы - у автора там char, а это значит, что если там и "юникод", то скорее всего utf8 (который байтовый) и значит ответ PPChar - хороший ответ, а упоминания юникода не нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну как упоминания не нужно... С D2009 - Char cтал WideChar. Не зная об этом, можно неверно интерпретировать содержимое полученного PPChar

Comment: а, они это сделали? я думал, что это первоапрельская шутка была...

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо. У меня в dll метод  `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* returnChar()
{
    char* chr = (char*)"asd";
    return chr;
}` , но при вызове в delphi мне приходит массив этих символов на непонятной кодировке. Как мне получить урегулировать этот момент?

Comment: @djoni, покажите, как выглядит эта непонятная кодировка.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов   䫔\壠ǒ'#$0804

Comment: @djoni, так обычно выглядит текст в однобайтной кодировке, прочитанный как UTF-16. Попробуйте в Delphi заменить Char на AnsiChar.